# How to synchronize SVG SMIL animations?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, smil

I am trying to synchronise two animations using *'syncbase'* value

```
...

<path
  d="M0 0 H100 V50 H0 Z"
  fill="purple"
>
  <animate
    id="anim1"
    attributeName="d"
    to="M0 0 H20 V50 H0 Z"
    begin="indefinite"
    end="indefinite"
    dur="2s"
    fill="freeze"
  />
</path>
<path
  d="M0 50 H100 V100 H0 Z"
  fill="pink"
>
  <animate
    id="anim2"
    attributeName="d"
    to="M0 50 H20 V100 H0 Z"
    begin="anim1.begin"
    end="anim1.end"
    dur="2s"
    fill="freeze"
  />
</path>

...
```

After repeated restarting before animation finished, the second animation eventually goes out of sync:

[image: out of sync visualisation]

Check out [**this demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Omnivoree/6fqahxbw/)

It is possible to restart all animations manually, hovewer the problem arises when complexity of svg element increases and there are many animations. If it was possible to chain SMIL animations like in this (not working) example it would simplify very much.

How to restart several animations with single call of `beginElement` and/or `endElement`?

**EDIT:** Out of sync happens in chrome only.

Comment: I can't get the animations to go out of sync.

Comment: @RobertLongson Just found out that this happens i chrome only. In firefox everything is fine.

Comment: Report Chrome bugs to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: I did, here it is: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1014419&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified